# Elementtree: Extract nodes and write to file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am looking for a way to extract a node out of a tree, make it a new tree and write it to a file.

```
<content>
    <book id="A">
        <chapter />
        <chapter />
    </book>
    <book id="B">
    <book id="C">
</content>
```

In this example it would be book@a which should become a.xml with `<book>` as root-element:

```
<book id="A">
   <chapter />
   <chapter />
</book>
```

I use ElementTree. My first try was to findall book@a in a for-loop and use .write or .tostring, but this didn't work at all or it resulted in a new xml with the content [<Element 'book' at 0x00000000031DD1D8>] :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find first element `book` with `find` or `findall`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data_as_string="""
<content>
    <book id="A">
        <chapter />
        <chapter />
    </book>
    <book id="B"></book>
    <book id="C"></book>
</content>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(data_as_string)
print ET.tostring(root.findall('book')[0])
print ET.tostring(root.find('book'))
```

It will print:

```
<book id="A">
        <chapter />
        <chapter />
    </book>

<book id="A">
        <chapter />
        <chapter />
    </book>
```